# How can i set images on custom keyboard similar to Bitmoji app in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating custom keyboard  programatically in objective c  for ios8.
similar to Bitmoji app
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bitmoji-keyboard-your-avatar/id868077558?mt=8

but my problem is that the image is not set to uimageview . How can I solve this?

If anyone know please reply as answer or any suggestion will also acceptable.

Thanks!